# Where to get sybase ASE 15.x for windows 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, sybase-ase15

where can I find setup for `sybase ASE 15.x` for windows 64 bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since this is clearly not a programming related question

Answer (score 0):

See this location for free download: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/oltp-db

Comment: The link is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

There's a 90-day evaluation version at https://www.sap.com/products/sybase-ase.html (click on 'free trial'). This is ASE 16, not 15. 
The developer version is no longer being offered by SAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Sybase customer it should be available through the support channel/web site.